# ACCESS 2007, Linked Table, Locking Back End DB for other users when open

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, linked-tables

I have a problem with tables linked to BE database.

Opening the table on FE database with linked tables by specific user locks the BE database for others, even for read.

An error Run-time 3045 comes when somebody wants to use a linked table.
Same as open BE database by msaccess, "Cannot block the file", and open .laccdb - "Permission denied"

Every user have same rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Vendor installed on its server the update with prevent data leakage, without information...

That update blocks opening files for multiple users.